# the best start time of applying for postdoc position?

Tags: postdocs

I'm a 3rd year PhD student in the UK. Due to the specialty of my topic (sociology), I spent two years collecting data, and now I plan to write up three manuscripts during my 3 rd year. My supervisors want me to graduate within one year (or 1.5 years), but I'm not sure if I can successfully find a job after my graduation, so I plan to simultaneously look for postdoc positions.

My question is, if I plan to graduate within 1 year, is it too early for me to start applying for postdoc positions? Because if I start right now, I haven't had any publications (I've submitted one but still under review, and another two are under writing).

Comment: If [realistic expected time of graduation] is earlier than [start of postdoc position] and you want the position, then you should apply the position. It really is as simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't too early to start the search. It takes time and you don't really want a gap to happen. In the worst case you learn some things about the process and what to expect.

People should understand the situation if you explain it well.

In your CV you should have a section on work in progress listing what you are currently doing. If you have preliminary versions of those three papers, even outlines, list them there.

If your supervisor is strongly supportive it should help as well.